# How to fillText upon clicking submit button on Vaadin canvas?

Tags: java, canvas, drawing, vaadin

I have a canvas which allows bounding boxes to be drawn. On the mouseDown function is where the starting x-y coordinates are pushed into an array as an object and on the mouseUp listener, that is when the actual drawing of the box takes place and once it is drawn, it will access the same array and edit the values of the width and height etc. In my MainLayout, I have a submit button to pass box name into the same array of objects. However, what I want to do now is for the box name to appear on top of the box (using fillText) once the submit button is clicked. I have tried putting the fillText inside my mouseUp listener, but it does not work as the box name has not yet been passed until the user clicks on Submit.

Here is my mouseDown and mouseUp listener in Canvas.java:

```
private static CanvasRenderingContext2D context;
    private Element element;
    private boolean mouseSelect = false;
    private double endX;
    private double endY;
    public static int boxCount = 0;

    public static ArrayList <BoundingBox> arrayBoxes = new ArrayList<BoundingBox>();
    public static ArrayList <MousePosition> mousePosArray = new ArrayList<MousePosition>();
    public static ArrayList <SelectBox> selectBoxes = new ArrayList<SelectBox>();
    private List<Runnable> mouseMoveListeners = new ArrayList<>(0);

element.addEventListener("mousedown", event -> {  // Retrieve starting x and y position

            Element boundingBoxResult = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult);

            JsonObject evtData = event.getEventData();

            double xBox = evtData.getNumber("event.x");
            double yBox = evtData.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-x", String.format("%f", xBox));
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-y", String.format("%f", yBox));

            BoundingBox newBox = new BoundingBox("","", xBox, yBox, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            arrayBoxes.add(newBox);

//            SelectBox select = new SelectBox(xBox, 0.0, yBox, 0.0);
//            selectBoxes.add(0, select);

            mouseIsDown=true;

            mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);

        }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");

    element.addEventListener("mouseup", event -> {  // Draws box + selection of boxes

    Element boundingBoxResult2 = ElementFactory.createDiv();
    element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult2);

    JsonObject evtData2 = event.getEventData();

    endX = evtData2.getNumber("event.x");
    endY = evtData2.getNumber("event.y");
    boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-x", String.format("%f", endX));
    boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-y", String.format("%f", endY));

    double xcoordi = 0;
    double ycoordi = 0;
    double boxWidth = 0;
    double boxHeight = 0;

    for (int i = boxCount; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(endX);
        System.out.println(endY);
        arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).setEndX(endX);
        arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).setEndY(endY);
        if (arrayBoxes.get(i).getYcoordi() != arrayBoxes.get(i).getEndY()) {  // If startY and endY is the same, means user selected a box and not drew a box
            arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).setWidth(endX, arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).xcoordi);
            arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).setHeight(endY, arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).ycoordi);
            xcoordi = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getXcoordi();
            ycoordi = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getYcoordi();
            boxWidth = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getWidth();
            boxHeight = arrayBoxes.get(boxCount).getHeight();
            boxCount++;

            context.beginPath();
            context.setStrokeStyle("green");
            context.setLineWidth(2);
            context.strokeRect(xcoordi, ycoordi, boxWidth, boxHeight);
            context.stroke();
            context.fill();

        } else {
            if (arrayBoxes.size() > 0) {
                arrayBoxes.remove(arrayBoxes.size() - 1);
                mouseSelect = true;

                SelectBox select = new SelectBox(endX, endY);
                selectBoxes.add(0, select);
            }
        }
    }

    if (mouseSelect == true) {
        int selectedBox = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++) {
            if (arrayBoxes.get(i).getXcoordi() < selectBoxes.get(0).getSelectX() &&  selectBoxes.get(0).getSelectX() < arrayBoxes.get(i).getEndX())
                if (arrayBoxes.get(i).getEndY() > selectBoxes.get(0).getSelectY() && selectBoxes.get(0).getSelectY() > arrayBoxes.get(i).getYcoordi()) {
                    System.out.println("Selected Box Name: " + arrayBoxes.get(i).boxname);
                    selectedBox = i;

                    mouseSelect = false;
             }
             else {
             mouseSelect = false;
             }
        }
        context.beginPath();
        context.setStrokeStyle("yellow");
        context.setLineWidth(2);
        context.strokeRect(arrayBoxes.get(selectedBox).getXcoordi(), arrayBoxes.get(selectedBox).getYcoordi(), arrayBoxes.get(selectedBox).boxWidth, arrayBoxes.get(selectedBox).boxHeight);
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();

    }


    System.out.println(arrayBoxes.toString());

    mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);

}).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");
```

MainLayout.java:

```
public class MainLayout extends Div {

    private CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx;
    private Canvas canvas;
    ArrayList<MousePosition> mousePosArray = Canvas.getMousePosArray();
    ArrayList<BoundingBox> bb = Canvas.getArrayBoxes();
    public static int count = 0;

Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
submitButton.addClickListener(event -> {
    bb.get(Canvas.boxCount - 1).setName(boxname.getValue());
    bb.get(Canvas.boxCount - 1).setBoxcategory(boxcategory.getValue());
    boxname.clear();
    boxcategory.clear();
    System.out.println(bb.toString());

    System.out.println("Box Count: " + Canvas.boxCount);

});
add(submitButton);
submitButton.addClassName("submitButton");
```

Any help is really appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just a method in your Canvas to draw the text

```
submitButton.addClickListener(event -> {
    BoundingBox box = bb.get(bb.size() - 1);
    box.setName(boxname.getValue());
    box.setBoxcategory(boxcategory.getValue());
    Canvas.redrawBox(box);
    boxname.clear();
    boxcategory.clear();
}
```

And in Canvas.java

```
public static void redrawBox(BoundingBox box) {
    // Insert real code to draw text here
    context.doSomething(box.getName());
}
```